# send textBox values to controller from cshtml (asp.net mvc)

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want get a values from web client and save it in database, but I don't know how call my controller methods from cshtml

```cs
@{
    @ViewBag.Title;
    @model Homi.Controllers.HomeController
    Homi.Controllers.HomeController obj = (Homi.Controllers.HomeController)ViewData["h"];
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/style.css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/rest.css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/font.css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/font2.css")

</head>
<body>
                Register

                <div>
                  <input type="username" id="Username required="required" />

                  </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="password" id="Password" required="required" />
                    <label for="Password">Password</label>

                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="password" id="Repeat Password" required="required"/>
                    <label for="Repeat Password">Repeat Password</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button><span>Next</span></button>
                </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/Content/index.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Content/jquery.js")

</body>
</html>
```

for example I have this code on my mind but you know it's doesn't work:

```html
<div onclick=@obj.setp(username.text, password.text)>
     <button><span>Next</span></button>
     </div>
```

I want when I click on "Next" button my method calling.
and this is part of my controller, the method that I want to call:

```
namespace Homi.Controllers{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult setp(string usename, string password)
    {
        WebAdmin wa = new WebAdmin();
        wa.InsertToDb(username, password);
        return View("userAccess");
    }}}
```

it's very important to me that I don't change my html code style

thank you for your help

Comment: You need to submit your form (or use ajax to post the values if you want to stay on the same page.

Comment: no I want to go in another page\

Comment: You need to go to the MVC site and learn the basics

Comment: I have submit button, in my css libraries that I delete those from above, and next button do submit button but I want to know how set method call for onclick, is there antway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your input fields inside a form tag and submit the form

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("setp","home"))
{
   <input type="text" name="Username" required="required" />
   <input type="text" name="Password" required="required" />
   <input type="submit" value="Next"/>
}
```

When razor executes the page, it will generate a `form` tag in the place of `@using(Html.BeginForm` line where the action is set to `"home/setp"`(*Check the view source in browser*). As long as your form element name's matches with your HttpPost action method parameter name's, values of the textboxes will be available in those when the form is submitted.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult setp(string Username, string password)
{ 
  //do something
}
```

Comment: thank you for your great help, I used that you wrote above on a empty project and it's worked but when used this on my main project(code above) it's doesn't worked?!!

Comment: Ok, I changed id to name and add type for my buttons and those worked, thank you again